# how to configure weblogic to resolve SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY?

Tags: java, weblogic

I have recently activate ssl on weblogic. after that the port on which ssl is configured, cannot be opened in firefox. the error is "SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY".
Have I done anything wrong in weblogic ssl configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Weblogic appears to send insecure SSL keys. One way to solve this is to tell WLS to use more secure protocols.

1. set `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS1` in your startup script or setEnv (see [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/SECMG/ssl.htm))
2. Install unlimited-strength JCE **if** you encounter "Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers" error
3. Optionally, tweak which cipher suites you allow inside `config.xml`. Some of the default ciphers are weak, and later JVM versions [stop supporting them](https://serverfault.com/questions/684691/weblogic-mitigate-poodle-vulnerability-after-upgrade-and-still-use-cbc-ciphers) anyway.